# Delete Azure Subscription Completely with Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am looking for a powershell cmdlet that deletes the Azure subscription completely. I was not able to find one. I saw something similar posted 2 years back  [cannot remove azure subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869451/cannot-remove-azure-subscription/33870646#33870646)

Is there a way to remove the subscription completely (all resources associated to subscription)? I don't want to loop through and remove all resource groups.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such powershell cmdlet to delete Azure subscription.

At this point you should now be able to cancel the subscription through the portal.

For more details, “[Cancel your subscription for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-how-to-cancel-azure-subscription)”.

If you still have questions, [contact support](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) (Which is free of cost) to get your issue resolved quickly.